# Unexpected results using Element.querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, queryselector

Given the following markup (I've only included the relevant part for the sake of brevity)

```
<ul>
  <li id="item">
    <a href="#foo">Stuff</a>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#foo">Foo stuff</a></li>
      <li><a href="#bar">Bar Stuff</a></li>
      <li><a href="#foobar">Foo-Bar Stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Let's say that I have a reference to the *li* element with the ID of 'item' which I could get like this:

```
let item = document.querySelector('#item');
```

Now I need to retrieve the last anchor element within the nested *ul* list.  For this I'm going to use the 'last-child' selector.  This is what I initially tried:

```
let lastLink = item.querySelector('li:last-child > a');
```

I thought this would do the trick, but alas it actually returns the very first link in the markup ('Stuff').  I don't quite understand this as my base-element is already the 'item' element and I'm asking it to find the *li* element within that base-element which is the last-child of its parent and then return the *a* element from within it.

Indeed, if I do this:

```
let lastLink = item.querySelector('li:last-child');
```

It *does* actually return the last li element within the nested ul list, so why doesn't the first option work to simply get the *'a'* element within that?

Here are some other things I tried which *do* work:

```
let lastLink = item.querySelector('#item li:last-child > a');
```

However, since I already have a reference to the base element it seems pointless to specify its ID here.  These also work and return the correct *a* element:

```
let lastLink = item.querySelector('li ul li:last-child > a');
let lastLink = item.querySelector('li:last-child li:last-child > a');
```

My question is, why doesn't the 1st option work?  Appreciate if anyone can throw some light on the reason

Comment: Almost sounds like it could be a browser bug. Have you tried it in multiple browsers, out of curiosity?

Comment: You're expecting `.querySelector()` to work like jQuery `.find()`. `querySelector()` includes the starting element in its searchj.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing `rootElm.querySelector(selector)` essentially does:

```
for (const node of recursiveDescendantNodes) {
  if (node.matches(selector)) {
    return node;
  }
}
```

The `selector` is not broken down and analyzed to see if the first part of the selector starts lower than the root node - usually, all that specifying the root node does is indicate which descendants to search through.

Since the first `<a>` that points to `#foo` matches the selector passed, it's returned.

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('#item > a').matches('li:last-child > a')
);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="item">
    <a href="#foo">Stuff</a>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#foo">Foo stuff</a></li>
      <li><a href="#bar">Bar Stuff</a></li>
      <li><a href="#foobar">Foo-Bar Stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

There is a way to get around that behavior, though, by using `:scope` - which, in supported browsers, indicates "the element `querySelector` (or `querySelectorAll`) was called on", which is the functionality you're hoping to see.

```js
let item = document.querySelector('#item');
let lastLink = item.querySelector(':scope li:last-child > a');
console.log(lastLink);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="item">
    <a href="#foo">Stuff</a>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#foo">Foo stuff</a></li>
      <li><a href="#bar">Bar Stuff</a></li>
      <li><a href="#foobar">Foo-Bar Stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```